# Returning Only ID list, Want more data in Onclick

Tags: javascript, django, k-means, markerclusterer

I am using AnyCluster/Django

When I click on Markers, a Popup is open and only ID is appears on it, I want more details like name,city etc. at PopUp page

What code i use is :

```
# return all IDs of the pins contained by a cluster
def getClusterContent(self, custom_filterstring=""):

    x = self.params["x"]
    y = self.params["y"]

    cluster = Point(x, y, srid=self.input_srid)

    # request lnglat point
    cell_geos = self.maptools.getCellForPointAsGeos(cluster, self.zoom, self.gridSize, self.db_srid)

    cluster.transform(self.db_srid)

    query_geometry = None

    for geometry in self.cache["geometries"]:
        geos = GEOSGeometry(geometry)

        if cluster.within(geos):
            query_geometry = geos.intersection(cell_geos)
            break


    filterstring = self.constructFilterstring(json.loads(self.cache["filters"]))
    filterstring += custom_filterstring

    kmeans_list = self.params["ids"]
    kmeans_string = (",").join(str(k) for k in kmeans_list)

    entries_queryset = Gis.objects.raw('''
                SELECT * FROM ( 
                  SELECT kmeans(ARRAY[ST_X(%s), ST_Y(%s)], %s) OVER () AS kmeans, "%s".*
                  FROM "%s" WHERE %s IS NOT NULL AND ST_Intersects(%s, ST_GeometryFromText('%s', %s) ) %s
                ) AS ksub
                WHERE kmeans IN (%s)
                ''' %(geo_column_str, geo_column_str, BASE_K, geo_table,
                      geo_table, geo_column_str, geo_column_str, query_geometry.ewkt, self.db_srid, filterstring,
                      kmeans_string ))


return entries_queryset
```

Comment: i don't really get the exact question/problem u have. could you pls explain any further?

Comment: and please show how you are generating the popup